# C++ * vs [] as a function parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, parameters, struct

What is the difference between:

```
void foo(item* list)
{
    cout << list[xxx].string;
}
```

and

```
void this(item list[])
{
    cout << list[xxx].string;
}
```

Assuming item is:

```
struct item
{
    char* string;
}
```

With the pointer pointing to the first of an array of chars

and `list` is just an array of items...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To the compiler, there is no difference.

It reads different though. `[]` suggests you want to pass an array to the function, whereas `*` could also mean just a simple pointer.

Note that arrays decay to pointers when passed as parameters (in case you didn't already know).

Comment: +1 for "Note that arrays decay to pointers when passed as parameters". I did not know that, interesting to know.

Comment: Not only do array expressions decay to pointers, when you specify an array type as a function parameter, it actually gets changed to a pointer type for all purposes, including overloading, `sizeof`, and `decltype`.  You can even declare it one way and define it a different way (but you probably shouldn't).

Comment: It would be good to add the text from the standard, so as to avoid giving anyone the impression that arrays and pointers are the same in general. Function parameters are just a special case where the standard states "After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” [...] is adjusted to be “pointer to T” [...]." [dcl.fct] 8.3.5/5.

Answer (score 3):

They are the same - completely synonymous. And the second is `item list[]`, not `item[]list`.

However it is customary to use `[]` when the parameter is used like an array and `*` when it's used like a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

FYI:

```
void foo(int (&a)[5]) // only arrays of 5 int's are allowed
{
}

int main()
{
  int arr[5];
  foo(arr);   // OK

  int arr6[6];
  foo(arr6); // compile error
}
```

but `foo(int* arr)`, `foo(int arr[])` and `foo(int arr[100])` are all equivalent